# return rows where sum on a field less than a given value

Tags: mysql, sql

My knowledge of  MySQL is basic.  I want to build a query to return all rows that sum a given value, in ascending order.  I can't figure out how I can do that. Using sum() only returns one row. I've tried a subquery but it returns all rows.   I don't want anybody do my work, I just want you to help me to figuring this out. 
Anybody have an idea?

How to retrieve all rows that its filed "value" sum 30
Example:

```
given value: 30
field to sum: value


table:
id name      value  order
1  name1     3      1
2  name2     10     6
3  name3     13     3
4  name4     5      8
5  name5     20     25
```

So, the query must return: 
id 1, id 3, id 2, id 4

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The listed rows do not add up to 30 (the result is 31).  Correct rows (could be) - 2, 5.  What happens if there is more than one way to get a result?

Comment: Yes, result is 31 because I need start to sum in this order: 1, 3, 6, 8. How in the row with order 8 is the value more closer to 30, query must retrieve that rows.

Comment: Please clarify the question! edit:whoops, guess I hadn't refreshed the page in a while. sorry!

Answer (score 3):

```
set @total:=0;
select id, name, value, `order`
from 
(select 
 id, name, value, `order`, 
 @total:=if(@total is null, 0, @total)+`order` as total
 from THE_TABLE
 order by `order`
) as derived 
where total<=30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using postgres as database, I think this does what you want. I'm not sure if it works similar in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id int,
name varchar(50),
value int,
order_ int
);

INSERT INTO test values (1,  'name1',     3,  1);
INSERT INTO test values (3,  'name3',     13, 3);
INSERT INTO test values (2,  'name2',     10, 6);
INSERT INTO test values (4,  'name4',     5,  8);
INSERT INTO test values (5,  'name5',     20, 25);

SELECT * FROM (SELECT  *, SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY order_) sumvalues FROM TEST) a WHERE sumvalues <30
```