# Query to get all records until the sum of column less than or equal a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get all the records in a table until the sum of a particular column is less than or equal to 'n'.

For example:

Table: data

```
slno     item       price

1        item1      1000
2        item2      2000
3        item3      3000
4        item4      4000
5        item5      5000
6        item6      6000
```

I want to get all records from above table until the sum(price) is less than or equal to 10000

So, with the above table my result would be first 4 records.

Comment: do this with php or something like that.

Comment: Use PL/SQL because this has to do a little bit of programming too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340013/return-rows-where-sum-on-a-field-less-than-a-given-value may be useful

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```sql
SELECT slno, item, price
  FROM
(
  SELECT slno, item, price, @t := @t + price total
    FROM table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @t := 0) i
   ORDER BY slno
) q
 WHERE total <= 10000
```

or

```sql
SELECT slno, item, price
  FROM
(
  SELECT slno, item, price, 
  (
    SELECT SUM(price)
      FROM table1
     WHERE slno <= t.slno
  ) total
    FROM table1 t
) q
 WHERE total <= 10000
 ORDER BY slno
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94de9/4)** demo

Comment: Thanks for your query. That meets my expectation but, it take much time to execute since my table has large number of data. Can you give me an optimized query with better performance

Comment: Can you give me an optimized query with better performance since the above query take more time to execute since the table I use has large data.

Comment: Both queries require a full table scan. Therefore to improve the performance one thing to do is to limit the number of source rows e.g. by introducing a `WHERE` clause with `slno` (or other column for that matter) range like `WHERE slno BETWEEN 1 AND 10` or `WHERE slno < 5000`...