# Fetch records with sum less then or equal to values in dataset

Tags: mysql, sql

This question is an extension of the question here [Query to get all records until the sum of column less than or equal a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824383/query-to-get-all-records-until-the-sum-of-column-less-than-or-equal-a-value)

**For the table: items**

| slno | item | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 | 1000 |
| 2 | item2 | 2000 |
| 3 | item3 | 3000 |
| 4 | item4 | 4000 |
| 5 | item5 | 5000 |
| 6 | item6 | 6000 |

**table: values**

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3500 |
| 2 | 6000 |
| 3 | 10000 |
| 4 | 21000 |

Get all the records in items having sum(price) equal to or less then each number in table values

such that the result will be

| id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 |
| 1 | item2 |
| 2 | item1 |
| 2 | item2 |
| 2 | item3 |
| 3 | item1 |
| 3 | item2 |
| 3 | item3 |
| 3 | item4 |
| 4 | item1 |
| 4 | item2 |
| 4 | item3 |
| 4 | item4 |
| 4 | item5 |
| 4 | item6 |

```
SELECT slno, item, price
  FROM
(
  SELECT slno, item, price, 
  (
    SELECT SUM(price)
      FROM table1
     WHERE slno <= t.slno
  ) total
    FROM table1 t
) q
 WHERE total <= 10000
 ORDER BY slno
```

above solution is for a single value of 10000 this solution was given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1920232/peterm

how to get records for each value in **table: values**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cumulative sum and then `join`:

```
select v.*, i.*
from (select i.*, sum(price) over (order by slno) as running_price
      from items i
     ) i join
     values v
     on i.running_price <= v.value
order by v.id, i.slno;
```

Comment: Although in this case "over (order by slno)" will work because the order of slno and price is increasing but in case of random order of slno and price "over (order by price)" is a better option.