# Select all data from table where the the sum of all data are equal to given number in Laravel Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a table that we can all a USER table

```
ID | Name | Category | Talent Fee
1    Tom    Clown      1200
2    John   Clown      900
3    Cris   Host       800
4    Joe    Organizer  1500
```

Now in my front end a CLIENT user wants to have a CLOWN,HOST,ORGANIZER in his event with a budget of 3200, now what I want to know is what will be the query to use if you want to retrieve all data which is the SUM or ALMOST THE SUM of the GIVEN NUMBER by the user and only one user pero category

So in the example table above the expected data return will be

```
John
Cris
Joe
```

So far I don't have much query to show since I really don't have the idea so far, so this query below is only getting the data from needs of client CLOWN, HOST, ORGANIZER

```
$available_users = User::where(function($eventneeds) use ($request){
        $eventneeds->where('category', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->input('need1') .'%')
            ->orWhere('category', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->input('need2') .'%')
            ->orWhere('category', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->input('need3') .'%');
        })
        ->get();
```

EDIT

so this [Query to get all records until the sum of column less than or equal a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824383/query-to-get-all-records-until-the-sum-of-column-less-than-or-equal-a-value) almost answer my question above, now what I want to in the query is also sum of  the given value which the category  should not be duplicated

```
slno     item       price   category
1        item1      1000    cat1
2        item2      2000    cat1
3        item3      3000    cat2
4        item4      4000    cat2
5        item5      5000    cat3
6        item6      6000    cat3
```

Answer (score 0):

so this [Query to get all records until the sum of column less than or equal a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824383/query-to-get-all-records-until-the-sum-of-column-less-than-or-equal-a-value) almost answer my question above, now what I want to in the query is also sum of  the given value which the category  should not be duplicated

```
slno     item       price   category
1        item1      1000    cat1
2        item2      2000    cat1
3        item3      3000    cat2
4        item4      4000    cat2
5        item5      5000    cat3
6        item6      6000    cat3
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a `SUM` you want to approach. First of all, this is how you can get all possible tuples:

```
SELECT Clown.`Name`,
       `Host`.`Name`,
       Organizer.`Name`,
       (Clown.`Talent Fee` + `Host`.`Talent Fee` + Organizer.`Talent Fee`) AS Cost
FROM `USER`;
```

Now, we want to modify the above as follows:

- we need a single record
- which has the smallest difference between actual cost and desired cost
- we have a variable value for desirable cost, I will assume it to be 50 here, but you will need to make it dynamic:

```
SELECT Clown.`Name`,
       `Host`.`Name`,
       Organizer.`Name`,
       (Clown.`Talent Fee` + `Host`.`Talent Fee` + Organizer.`Talent Fee`) AS Cost
FROM `USER`;
ORDER BY ABS((Clown.`Talent Fee` + `Host`.`Talent Fee` + Organizer.`Talent Fee`) - 50)
LIMIT 0, 1
```

The `ABS` ensures that you compute the actual difference as a positive value and the `LIMIT` ensures that you get only the tuple that is the best in meeting this criteria.

Comment: Nice, will try this out. Thanks much

Comment: @Noob I'm happy to help. If this answer solves your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.