# Get all records until the sum of column less than or equal a given value and category

Tags: sql

This is ALMOST answered by this thread [Query to get all records until the sum of column less than or equal a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824383/query-to-get-all-records-until-the-sum-of-column-less-than-or-equal-a-value)

Now the difference is that  I do have a **CATEGORY** column

```
slno     item       price   category
1        item1      1000    cat1
2        item2      2000    cat1
3        item3      3000    cat2
4        item4      4000    cat2
5        item5      5000    cat3
6        item6      6000    cat3
```

Now the **GIVEN value** is **10000** and **GIVEN categories** are **cat1, cat2, cat3**

Results should be, since these data met the condition of <= 10000

```
slno   item   price   category
1      item1  1000    cat1
3      item3  3000    cat2
5      item5  5000    cat3
```

the current query is this,

```
SELECT slno, item, price, category

 FROM
(
  SELECT slno, item, price, category,
  (
    SELECT SUM(price)
      FROM table1
     WHERE slno <= t.slno
  ) total
    FROM table1 t
) q
 WHERE total <= 10000
 ORDER BY slno
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the following result:

```
slno   item   price   category
1      item1  1000    cat1
3      item3  3000    cat2
5      item5  5000    cat3
```

try this query:

```
select * from categories GROUP BY category ORDER BY MIN(price) ASC;
```

or

```
select slno, item, MIN(price), category from categories GROUP BY category;
```

Comment: Hi, yea I want the following results above but not using that query I have certain conditions that needs to be meet to get  the results I need not just doing a group by